# Svelte: How to handle the custom writable store's async init's promise in the component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have several Svelte components and a custom writable store. The store has an `init` function which is `async` and which fills the store's value with some REST API's db's table's data. My components must all subscribe to this store by using autosubscription. At subscription, `init` must be called. The global idea is to implement CRUD operations on the db with CRUD operations on the store (useful to show the store's value, *i.e.* the db's table, with reactivity).

As `init` is `async` and, thus, returns a promise, I need to `await` it in my components. But since I use autosubscription (by prefixing the store name with `$`), how can I do that?

For example: `App.svelte` (the component):

```
<script>
    import { restaurant_store } from './Restaurant.js'
    export let name
</script>

<main>
    
    <!--- I need to handle the promise and rejection here -->
    {#each $restaurant_store as restaurant}
        <li>
            {restaurant.name}
        </li>
    {/each}
    

</main>
```

`Restaurant.js` (the store):

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export function createRestaurantsStore() {
    const { subscribe, update } = writable({ collection: [] })

    return {
        subscribe,

        init: async () => {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/restaurants')

            if(response.ok) {
                const json_response = await response.json()
                set({ collection: json_response })
                return json_response
            }

            throw Error(response.statusText)
        },

        insert: async (restaurant) => {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/restaurants', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(restaurant)
            })

            if(response.ok) {
                const json_response = await response.json()
                update(store_state => store_state.collection.push(json_response))
                return json_response
            }

            throw Error(response.statusText)
        },

        update: async (restaurant, id) => {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/restaurants/' + id, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(restaurant)
            })

            if(response.ok) {
                const json_response = await response.json()
                update(store_state => {
                    const current_id = store_state.collection.findIndex(e => e.id === id)
                    store_state.collection.splice(current_id, 1, json_response)
                })
                return json_response
            }

            throw Error(response.statusText)

        }

    }
}

export const restaurant_store = createRestaurantsStore()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Svelte provides a [built-in mechanism](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-await) to handle the possible states of promises within your template, so the same could look like this:

```html
<main>
    {#await restaurant_store.init()}
        <p>waiting for the promise to resolve...</p>
    {:then}
      {#each $restaurant_store as restaurant}
        <li>
          {restaurant.name}
        </li>
      {/each}
    {:catch error}
        <p>Something went wrong: {error.message}</p>
    {/await}
</main>
```

Checkout the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9545e8959d63499b92a1073ae2fe1600?version=3.43.1) for a live example.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't understand `init` function would not be called automatically by the store when defined. Thank you!

Comment: That REPL isn't actually working. It should also be noted that if you set/update on $restaurant_store, with that example the contents of the #await block will not be shown again. Here is a REPL that will re-show the contents of the #await block any time you update the store https://svelte.dev/repl/d78d7327830442ab87cc47bcee1033f9?version=3.43.1